# If $\vec{a}\;\;,\vec{b}\;\;,\vec{c}$ be three vectors such that $\vec{a}\times \vec{b} = \vec{c}$ and $\vec{c}\times \vec{a} = \vec{b}\;,$

Tags: vectors

If $\vec{a}\;\;,\vec{b}\;\;,\vec{c}$ be three vectors such that $\vec{a}\times \vec{b} = \vec{c}$ and $\vec{c}\times \vec{a} = \vec{b}\;,$ Then which one is right.

$\bf{Options::}$ $(a)\;\; \vec{a}\cdot \vec{b} = |\vec{c}|^2\;\;\;\;\;\; (b)\;\; \vec{c}\cdot \vec{a} = |\vec{b}|^2\;\;\;\;\;\; (c)\;\; \vec{b}\cdot \vec{c} = |\vec{a}|^2\;\;\;\;\;\; (d)\;\; \vec{a}||\left(\vec{b}\times \vec{c}\right).$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ above we have given $\vec{a}\times \vec{b} = \vec{c},$  Now put  value of $\vec{c}$ in and $\vec{c}\times \vec{a} = \vec{b}.$

So we get ${\left(\vec{a}\times \vec{b}\right)\times \vec{a}} = \vec{b}.\Rightarrow \vec{a}\times (\vec{a}\times \vec{b}) = -\vec{b}.$

Now Using $(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b})\vec{a}-|\vec{a}|^2\vec{b} = -\vec{b}.$

So from above we get $\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}=0$ and $|\vec{a}| =1$

Now I did not Understand how can we get answers.

Help me , Thanks

Comment: Why not try it with $i,j,k$?

Comment: HINT: The three vectors are perpendicular to each other.

Comment: Thanks Michel , But i have got $\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b} = 0$ and $\vec{a}\cdot \vec{c} =0\;,$ But i did not understand how can i calculate $\vec{b}\cdot \vec{c}=0$

Comment: Thanks  Jesse P Francis, You mean $\hat{i}\;\;,b=\hat{j}\;\;,c=\hat{k}$

Comment: @juantheron, yes! Since you just need to verify options!

Comment: Posted it as an answer not to leave the question unanswered!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\vec i,\vec j,\vec k$ satisfies the requirements in question: since you just need to verify the options!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $c=a\times b$ implies that $c$ is orthogonal to $a$ and $b$ so: $c \cdot a=0$ and $b \cdot c=0$.

also, from $b=c\times a$ we have $a\cdot b=0$ so the only possible answer is (d).

Answer (score 1):

Since $\vec{a}\times\vec{b}=\vec{c}$,so $\vec{c}$ is perpendicular to both $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.And since $\vec{c}\times\vec{a}=\vec{b}$,so $\vec{b}$ is perpendicular to both $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{c}$.So $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ are mutually perpendicular to each other.
Therefore,$\vec{a}||\vec{b}\times\vec{c}$.Option $(d)$ is correct.